# Wrong encoding in JSON output when working with Hapi, axios and cheerio

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding, cheerio, hapi.js

There's a website (which I don't manage) with

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

I'm building a Hapi server with cheerio, axios that reads some data from this website

This is how the website shows the data I'm getting

[image: website]

```
<span class="name">DÓLAR BNA</span>
```

I load that html on cheerio as

```
const response = await axios.get(url2Get);
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data.toString('ISO-8859-1'),{ decodeEntities: false });
// process with cheerio and build/send json response
```

But I still keep getting this in JSON output

[image: json output]

I've tried also installing package iconv-lite and doing

```
iconv.decode(Buffer.from(title), 'ISO-8859-1');
```

But no luck yet. Thanks for any advise

Comment: I think that's just your terminal being weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use axios with the config option *responseEncoding* set to '*binary*' like so:

```
const response = await axios.get(url2Get, {responseEncoding: 'binary'});
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data.toString('ISO-8859-1'),{ decodeEntities: false });
// process with cheerio and build/send json response
```

Comment: ISO-8859-1 didn't work, but latin1 did the trick. I've used responseEncoding:'binary' before, but the one thing left was to convert response.data.toString('latin1') with decodeEntities:false . Thanks @igorshmigor